# jsPDF unable to render minus sign from html and mathjax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, mathjax

I've been trying to create PDF documents with equations via jsPDF, html2canvas and [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

The equation will be displayed in HTML, and then rendered via mathjax to look like a mathematical equation.
Later on, the HTML code of the rendered equation will be transferred into a new PDF file via the `html()` method of the jsPDF library. This method takes HTML code and puts it in a PDF file.

For some reason, jsPDF replaces each minus sign (-) with a quotation mark (").

I added a demo test for you to see the problem, here is an additional link for it [codepen](https://codepen.io/jonaprojects/pen/JjMpoJL):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
          name="viewport">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jsPDF - for generating pdf files !-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML2Canvas - for generating PDF documents with math syntax !-->
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha512-BNaRQnYJYiPSqHHDb58B0yaPfCu+Wgds8Gp/gU33kqBtgNS4tSPHuGibyoeqMV/TJlSKda6FXzoEyYGjTe+vXA=="
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      MathJax = {
        tex2jax: {
          inlineMath: [
            ["$", "$"],
            ["\\(", "\\)"]
          ],
          displayMath: [
            ["$$", "$$"],
            ["\\[", "\\]"]
          ]
        }
      };


    </script>
    <style>
    mjx-container mjx-math {
    white-space: normal;
}

    </style>
    <script
            async
            id="MathJax-script"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.9/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"
    ></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mathExample">$ -3x^2 + 5 $</div>
<button id="myButton" onclick="createPDF()">Create a PDF document</button>
</body>
<script>
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    function createPDF(){
        var mathExample = document.querySelector("#mathExample");
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.html(mathExample, {
        callback: function(doc) {
            doc.save("output.pdf");
        },
        x: 15,
        y: 15
    });

    }


</script>
</html>
```

Here is an example for the mathjax equations in the actual application i'm building:

[image: mathjax]

And this is how they are shown in the PDF file

[image: pdf]

What am I missing here? Thanks for any help I'm desperate

EDIT: As suggested, it turns out that MathJax also appends style tags
when rendering equations. However, when I try adding a style tags to the pdf file jsPDF just crashes and I get the error: "Could not load dompurify"

Edit: It turns out that you have to load the font and style by your own, as Davide Cervone pointed out in the comments, and also added a link to a [github example](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/tree/master/examples/MathJax).

This is the final PDF file. Important to mention, stuff like matrices don't really work at least in this way, since the brackets stay small.

[image: SolvedPDF]

Comment: Are you transferring the CSS produced by MathJax as well?  The CSS sets up the fonts (as web fonts) and includes other needed styling.  The fonts clearly are not the right ones in your PDF, and that is probably the reason you are not getting the minus signs.  MathJax uses the full unicode range, and it may also be that jsPDF doesn't work well with that, as the minus sign is U+2212, and should be a minus in any font.  The fact that it isn't in the font being used suggests that it might not properly handle non-ASCII unicode characters.

Comment: I didn't know css is being generated, I'll try looking into that. Thanks

Comment: I tried, but jsPDF couldn't process the style tag. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: There seems to be a jsPDF MathJax example [here](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/tree/master/examples/MathJax).  It looks like you have to load the fonts by hand, and they don't really say how they created the needed data, but there is an example you could try out, and perhaps it would be sufficient for your needs.  Otherwise, you could consider using MathJax's SVG output, and see if jsPDF's SVG support will handle that.  You would want to turn of path caching in MathJax to make the SVG self-contained.

Comment: Hi, after playing with the github example for a while, I've managed to modify the code to work more or less. It doesn't work for all mathjax features such as matrices for instance, but for now it's good enough for my needs. Thank you!